# Create a map with clickable provinces/states using SVG, HTML/CSS, ImageMap

Tags: svg, mapping, imagemap, jquery-svg

I am trying to create an interactive map where users can click on different provinces in the map to get info specific to that province.

Example:

- archived: [http://www.todospelaeducacao.org.br/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120615063214/http://www.todospelaeducacao.org.br/)
- archived: [http://code.google.com/p/svg2imap/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120619042924/http://code.google.com/p/svg2imap//)

So far I've only found solutions that have limited functionality. I've only really searched for this using an SVG file, but I would be open to other file types if it is possible.

If anyone knows of a fully functioning way to do this (jQuery plug-in, PHP script, vector images) or a tutorial on how to do it manually please do share.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

jQuery plugin for decorating image maps (highlights, select areas, tooltips):

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

Disclosure: I wrote it.

Answer (score 21):

Sounds like you want a simple imagemap, I'd recommend to not make it more complex than it needs to be. Here's an article on [how to improve imagemaps with svg](http://web.archive.org/web/20131128162342/http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/improving-image-maps-with-svg-and-xslt/). It's very easy to do clickable regions in svg itself, just add some <a> elements around the shapes you want to have clickable.

A couple of options if you need something more advanced:

- http://jqvmap.com/
- http://jvectormap.com/
- http://polymaps.org/

Comment: Nice example, but the text get often garbled in FF (Chrome looks OK). Maybe the FF renderer it's a bit slow, what a pity...

Comment: This is the best answer. jqvmap and jvectormap are exactly what I was looking for. @CapelliC, they work great in FF 26. Also [This one is pretty good](http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/)

Answer (score 7):

I think it's better to divide my answer to 2 parts:

---

**A**-Create everything from scratch (using SVG, JavaScript, and HTML5):

1. Create a new HTML5 page
2. Create a new SVG file, each clickable area (province) should be a separate SVG Polygon in your SVG file,
   (I'm using Adobe Illustrator for creating SVG files but you can find many alternative software products too, for example [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/))
3. Add mouseover and click events to your polygons one by one

   ```
   <polygon points="200,10 250,190 160,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" 
       onmouseover="mouseOverHandler(evt)"
       onclick="clickHandler(evt)" />
   ```
4. Add a handler for each event in your JavaScript code and add your desired code to the handler

   ```
   function mouseOverHandler(evt) {};
   function clickHandler(evt) {};
   ```
5. Add the SVG file to your HTML page (I prefer inline SVG but you can use linked SVG file too)
6. Upload the files to your server

---

**B**-Use a software like [FLDraw Interactive Image Creator](http://www.fldraw.com/) (only if you have a map image and want to make it interactive):

1. Create an empty project and choose your map image as your base image when creating the new project
2. Add a Polygon element (from the Shape menu) for each province
3. For each polygon double click it to open the Properties window where you can choose an event type for mouse-over and click,
   also change the shape opacity to 0 to make it invisible
4. Save your project and Publish it to HTML5, FLDraw will create a new folder that contains all of the required files for your project that you can upload to your server.

---

Option (A) is very good if you are programmer or you have someone to create the required code and SVG file for you,
Option (B) is good if you don't want to hire someone or spend your own time for creating everything from scratch

You have some other options too, for example using HTML5 Canvas instead of SVG, but it's not very easy to create a Zoomable map using HTML5 Canvas, 
maybe there are some other ways too that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone will search for it - I used it on several sites, always the customization and RD possibilities were a perfect fit for what I needed. Simple and it is free to use:

[Clickable CSS Maps](http://winstonwolf.pl/clickable-maps/europe.html)

One note for more scripts on a site: I had some annoying problems with getting to work a map (that worked as a graphic menu) in Drupal 7. There where many other script used, and after handling them, I got stuck with the map - it still didn't work, although the jquery.cssmap.js, CSS (both local) and the script in the  where in the right place. Firebug showed me an error and I suddenly eureka - a simple oversight, I left the  script code as it was in the example and there was a conflict. Just change the front function "$" to "jQuery" (or other handler) and it works perfect. :]

Here's what I ment (of course you can put it before  instead of the ):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($){
        $('#map-country').cssMap({'size' : 810});
       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to [SVG to Script](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php)
with your SVG the default output is the map in SVG
Code which adds events is also added but is easily identified and can be altered as required.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work... I can get the SVG to turn into code, and managed to obtain SVG code through Illustrator from the file, but I cannot manage to wrap the SVG paths with an anchor tag.

Comment: <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    width="1343.791px" height="932.583px" viewBox="0 0 1343.791 932.583" enable-background="new 0 0 1343.791 932.583"
    xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="Panama">
    <path fill="#FDF9D1" stroke="#918E8F" d="..."/>
    </g>
    </svg>

Comment: Hmm your extracting code from the SVG. This will have to be incorporated with what you generated. Can you let me know the name of the file and I will dig around and find it?

Comment: you can find the exact SVG I am trying to use at this URL: http://www.unidosporlaeducacion.com/images/panama.svg

Comment: Its a very complicated SVG file... Should I use a simpler one? I could create a simplified artwork in AI

Comment: I've been out this is what I found http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/codeconvertedsvg.php?q=Panama This is scaled, let me know if I can be of anymore help...

Comment: thanks for the help.. I found a way around it using attributes in Illustrator and then using that program's save for web feature to save it as an html image map with a png file...  then I am using the solution posted above

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [makeaclickablemap](http://www.makeaclickablemap.com) for my province maps for some time now and it turned out to be a really good fit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirements and finally this [Map converter](https://github.com/datag/jvectormap/wiki/Map-converter-notes) worked for me.  It is the best plugin for any map generation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another image map plugin I wrote to enhance image maps: https://github.com/gestixi/pictarea

It makes it easy to highlight all the area and let you specify different styles depending on the state of the zone: normal, hover, active, disable.

You can also specify how many zones can be selected at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you:

```
$("#svgEuropa [id='stallwanger.it.dev_shape_DEU']").on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

[Source](https://www.maps4office.com/create-clickable-map-use-jquery-and-svg/)

Answer (score -1):

You have quite a few options for this:

1 - If you can find an SVG file for the map you want, you can use something like [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/) to add click listeners for your states/regions, this solution is the most customizable...

2 - You can use dedicated tools such as [clickablemapbuilder (free)](http://clickablemapbuilder.com/) or [makeaclickablemap (i think free also)](http://www.makeaclickablemap.com/).

[disclaimer] Im the author of [clickablemapbuilder.com](http://clickablemapbuilder.com) :)

Answer (score -2):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($){
        $('#map-country').cssMap({'size' : 810});
       });
    </script>
```

strong text

Comment: Not strong enough to help us understand why this solution should be preferred over the ones which actually contain an explanation.